# Does Android Studio keep another version of Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Here is my Gradle setting:

[image: my gradle setting]

On my developing app, I usually click the button below and everything goes well.

[image: run]

I want to write a script to auto run my build every day. 
I tried `gradlew assembleRelease` and `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.4/bin/gradle assembleRelease` but it start downloading all dependencies, I have bad network so I can't run the build.

Obviously I have downloaded all the dependencies before because I could click that "run" button and launch my app. It seems Android Studio keep a gradle cache itself and provider another `gradlew` program.

How could I build my app from the command line with my bad network. Thanks!